# Execute function with jQuery if widget added or removed?

Tags: customization, jquery, widgets

I am trying to create a function which refreshes a specific div if a widget is added or removed with the Customizer.

I found this jQuery, which I thought would only execute if a widget is added or removed:

```
jQuery(document).on('widget-updated widget-added', function(){
    // your code to run
});
```

But even if I place a console log as the code to run, it doesn't detect that a widget is added or removed. (I press Publish in Customizer).

Any ideas?

Comment: WordPress has a way to add support for selective refresh for widgets. It's described here: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/03/22/implementing-selective-refresh-support-for-widgets/

Comment: I think that is something else. Because when adding the widget to the Customizer it is updated and work fine. What I am looking for is to automatically refresh the page displaying this widget (outside Customizer) if a change has happened, a widget has been added or removed. So I am looking for a jQuery which detects this change and refreshes the page.

Comment: So you want to interrupt any users who might be viewing the page as soon as you change a widget? Can I ask why?

Comment: Yes exactly, because the site is displayed on a display without keyboard or mouse, and when a change to the site happens it should be reloaded. But the question is how to do this when a widget is added or removed. EDIT: An alternative method would be to detect when the Customizers Publish-button is pressed, and issue a refresh. But I don't know how.